# Calling class in swift from kotlin/native framework

Tags: kotlin

I followed the tutorial: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html and successfully export a jar file for Android and a framework for iOS. After I want to implement something more complex. I uses Android Studio Kotlin with the codes below:

Model.kt:

```
package org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.BusinessLogic

abstract class Model{

var _id:Long = 0

abstract fun PolymorphismTest()
}
```

Sales.kt:

```
package org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.BusinessLogic

class Sales : Model() {

init {
    this._id = _counter
    _counter++

}
companion object {

    private var _counter: Long = 0

}

fun get_counter(): Long {
    return _counter
}

private val _salesItems:MutableList<SalesItem> = ArrayList()

fun SalesItems(): MutableList<SalesItem> {
    return _salesItems
}

fun TotalAmount():Double
{
    var totalAmount:Double = 0.0
    for(aSalesItem in _salesItems)
    {
        totalAmount += aSalesItem.SubTotal()
    }

    return totalAmount
}

fun AddSalesItem(salesItem: SalesItem)
{
    this._salesItems.add(salesItem)
}

fun AddSalesItem(itemName:String, itemCode:String, quantity:Double, amount:Double )
{
    val aSalesItem = SalesItem()
    aSalesItem._itemCode = itemCode
    aSalesItem._itemName = itemName
    aSalesItem._quantity = quantity
    aSalesItem._amount = amount
    this.AddSalesItem(aSalesItem)
}

fun ToString(): String {
    return "Sales: $this._id"
}


override fun PolymorphismTest() {
    println("This is method from Sales")
}

}
```

SalesItem.kt:

```
package org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.BusinessLogic

class SalesItem : Model() {

init {
    this._id = _counter
    _counter++
}
companion object {

    private var _counter: Long = 0
}

fun get_counter(): Long {
    return _counter
}

var _sales: Sales? = null

var _amount:Double = 0.toDouble()
var _quantity:Double = 0.toDouble()

fun SubTotal(): Double {
    return _amount * _quantity
}

var _itemName:String? = null
var _itemCode:String? = null


fun Sales():Sales?{
    return _sales
}

fun SalesItem(sales:Sales)
{
    _sales = sales
    this._id = _counter
    _counter++
}

fun ToString(): String {
    return "Sales: $this._id"
}

override fun PolymorphismTest() {
    println("This is method from SalesItem")
}
}
```

I export these codes into a framework then imported into Xcode and using Swift to call

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SharedCode
class ViewController: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad(){
     super.viewDidLoad()

     print("Creating Sales Object")
     let sales = Sales() //error here

   }
 }
```

After that I met the errors of

> Instances of kotlin.Error, kotlin.RuntimeException and subclasses aren't propagated from Kotlin to Objective-C/Swift.
>   Other exceptions can be propagated as NSError if method has or inherits @Throws annotation.
>   Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.BusinessLogic.Sales.Companion@228b588
>           at 0   SharedCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin/Native has different threading model. The idea is that an instance of an object has to be frozen to be accessed from all threads. There is `.freeze()` extension method for that.

By default, `object Smth` are also frozen. In the code sniper you have mutable fields in companion object.

A possible workaround could be to replace companion object with an ordinary class, that you create explicitly

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/concurrency.html#concurrency-in-kotlinnative

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/immutability.html#immutability-in-kotlinnative

Comment: removing companion object and creation a class and initialising in init or constructor fixed the problem, it seems like companion object not supported in kotlin 1.4.10 or 1.4.0